# form_for ajax call without jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm having trouble getting the remote option to work with form_for. Rails 4. jQuery is not an option. I'm wondering whether jQuery is required or there is a mistake in my code.

The form (an update action, which works on the server end).

```
<%= form_for @image, :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true, :url => image_path(@image, :format => :json), :data => {type: :json}, :method => "patch", :html => {:class => 'base-64-edit-form', :multipart => true, :id => "base-64-edit-form", :class => "hide" } do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :update_image_data %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :width, :value => @image.width %>
<%= f.hidden_field :height, :value => @image.height %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :folder_id %>
 <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The form submission:

```
document.getElementById("image_update_image_data").setAttribute("value", data);
document.getElementById("image_width").setAttribute("value", parseInt(pixel_canvas.style.width));
document.getElementById("image_height").setAttribute("value", parseInt(pixel_canvas.style.height));
document.getElementById("image_folder_id").setAttribute("value", config.folder_id);
document.body.addEventListener("ajax:success", function(e){
                console.log("ajax SUCCESS");
            })
document.body.addEventListener("ajax:failure", function(e){
                console.log("ajax FAILURE");
            })
document.getElementById("base-64-edit-form").submit();
document.getElementById("loading").classList.add("active");
```

The controller action:

```
 def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @image.update(image_params)
    format.json { render :json => true}
  else
    format.json { render :json => @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

A successful update renders a page with the word "true" on it, rather than returning a true json value to the callback. So I am assuming that the ajax call is not made and no magic happens. Could this be because I am not using jQuery?

If I replace

```
format.json { render :json => true}
```

with

```
format.json { head :no_content }
```

the page is not re-rendered, Chrome gets a 200, but with an error.

Comment: `jQuery is not an option` So purpose of jQuery tag??? FYI, what can be done in jQuery, can be done in javascript because basically, jQuery is javascript

Comment: I don't know if the ajax/remote option for form_for is dependent on jQuery or not. I'm trying to find out.